# Is $( ) JavaScript or jQuery notation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to differentiate between the JavaScript and jQuery; to sculpt accurate models of what the two represent.

Originally, I had *thought* that jQuery was a collection of libraries, plug-ins, and tool kits. I came to this notion due to what a peer told me, from reading around on the Internet, and also because I've been using Slick (an image carousel) which I downloaded from jQuery.

Yet as I've been developing more and getting to know JavaScript, instead of doing specific calls to a library I downloaded (Slick):

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({...});
```

I've lately been doing calls like the following:

```
$('.mid-buttons').click(function(){...});
```

Which confuses me, because I never downloaded any jQuery library other than Slick, so is ***.click*** part of some automatically downloaded jQuery library or part of what comes with JavaScript?

Also, is $() used for any calls to an object in HTML/CSS or is the methods being called, ***.slick*** or ***.click***, what dictates the usage of $( )?

I know that these are extremely amateur questions but it's been tough finding a resource that explicetely differentiates the distinction I am trying to make/understand. Thanks!

Comment: Note that I come from a C/C++ background. I'm used to calling libraries, but this concept of, "If it's a library, we don't call it C++, we call it c++Query" doesn't  make sense to me.

Comment: @8protons You're a victim of a common plague. For some reason, a lot of people believe that jQuery is somehow removed from Javascript. It really is nothing but a Javascript library written in Javascript. That's it.

Comment: @8protons — There are a lot of cargo cult copy/paste web page authors out there. Many of them don't understand the difference between JavaScript and jQuery. That doesn't mean calling some JavaScript "jQuery" just because it calls the jQuery library is correct or normal though.

Comment: It's a good and valid question -- sad to see it downvoted.

Comment: @MikeC "It really is nothing but a Javascript library written in Javascript." Elegant and to the point, thank you. Is it wrong of me to feel like this is convoluted or is there a method to the naming madness?

Comment: @8protons There's no method, only madness ;) Why do people refer to them as separate things? Because they're confused. Why does jQuery use `$`? Because it's a convenient identifier that stands out.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for the insight; so it's only really jQuery if it's officially in the jQuery website/DB?

Comment: @8protons — jQuery is jQuery, other things many use it or be plugins for it. jQuery.com has a searchable database of plugins, but they are plugins and have their own names and just depend on jQuery without being part of it.

Comment: @Cymen Thank you; I don't understand why it's getting down votes so quickly. I tried  not to ask the flat, "What is jQuery?" or "jQuery vs JavaScript" questions. I was specific in my details and have a more specific question regarding the use of the delimiters for jQuery/JS. Any suggested edits to make this a better question?

Comment: @MikeC Thank you! Okay, "Why does jQuery use $? Because it's a convenient identifier that stands out" made complete sense to me. I think I'm getting it now; $ is really native to the JS language and jQuery, being simply JS, is just utilizing the identifier $?

Comment: @8protons You got it! That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript is a programming language.

jQuery is a library written in JavaScript.

`$` is a valid identifier name in JavaScript.

jQuery uses `$` as the variable name for its main function (it also uses `jQuery`). This function is [defined in the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

When you call it as a function (generally with the syntax `$(some arguments here)`), the return value is a jQuery object. These usually wrap some DOM nodes.

Slick is a plugin. It is another library that expands the functionality of jQuery (using [the jQuery plugins api](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)). It provides a method that you can call on jQuery objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response! "$(some arguments here)), the return value is a jQuery object." Just so I'm understanding it correctly, said return value is an object to be used with some attached jQuery method like .click or .slick?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery is a library.](http://jquery.com/) It's got it's own set of functionality. What you downloaded was a jQuery plugin, i.e., it *extends* jQuery.

jQuery itself is just Javascript. Nothing more, nothing less. You can even read an [annotated version of the source code here.](https://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/)

`$()` is the jQuery function. It's the basic starting point for most things in jQuery. In it's simplest form, it's a way of grabbing DOM nodes and wrapping them in a special wrapper which has access to the rest of the jQuery API.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is typically exposed as both `$` and `jQuery`. You can run see that they are the same by running `$.fn.jquery` and `jQuery.fn.jquery` which will give you the version. Or run `$ == jQuery`. So even though `$` looks special, it's just a function like any other and by putting `()` after `$` you are running the jQuery function.

Things like `click` are part of the core jQuery. It has a monolithic approach to plugins in that they augment the jQuery instance variable (`$` or `jQuery`). If you try CommonJS, you'll see a non-monolithic approach to how different pieces of JavaScript code can be pulled together.

Comment: "You can run see that they are the same by running $.fn.jquery and jQuery.fn.jquery". Giving me an example to prove it to myself was brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`$()` is valid JavaScript grammar. jQuery is a library and has defined the function`$`. In JavaScript you call a function with `()`.

Comment: $ = jQuery defined function
() = JavaScript function parameter delimiter 
$() = ?

Sorry, the combination of the two is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @8protons `$()` is just a function call. It calls the `$` function.

Comment: @8protons `$` is a function, right? So you need to call it with `()`, otherwise it's just another value. It's like writing `alert` with no `()`. It wouldn't do anything without them.